# Porting code from pandas doesn't work in polars why?

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying polars for the first time, it seems like a drop in replacement. But, getting stuck at alot of places For example snippet below work well in pandas but not in polars

```
product_sold_out_mask = ((df_product_data['quantity_available'] == 0) & (df_product_data['reorder_threshold'] >= 0))

df_product_data.loc[product_sold_out_mask, 'sold_out_date'] = df_product_data['transaction_date'] - pd.to_timedelta(df_product_data['reorder_threshold'], unit='D')
df_product_data.loc[~product_sold_out_mask, 'sold_out_date'] = pd.NaT

df_product_data.loc[df_product_data['sold_price'] <= 0, 'sold_price'] = -999
df_product_data.loc[df_product_data['sold_price'] > 2.0 * df_product_data['current_price'], 'sold_price'] = df_product_data['current_price']
```

Example:

```
import polars as pl

data = {
    'transaction_date': ['2023-06-01', '2023-06-02', '2023-06-03'],
    'quantity_available': [0, 2, 1],
    'reorder_threshold': [5, 1, 3],
    'current_price': [10.0, 12.0, 8.0],
    'sold_price': [0, 15.0, 20.0],
}

df_product_data = pl.DataFrame(data)

product_sold_out_mask = (
    (df_product_data['quantity_available'] == 0)
    & (df_product_data['reorder_threshold'] >= 0)
)

df_product_data = df_product_data.with_column(
    pl.when(product_sold_out_mask)
    .then(pl.date("transaction_date") - pl.date("reorder_threshold").cast(pl.Date))
    .otherwise(pl.lit(None))
    .alias("sold_out_date")
)

df_product_data = df_product_data.with_column(
    pl.when(df_product_data['sold_price'] <= 0).then(-999)
    .when(df_product_data['sold_price'] > 2.0 * df_product_data['current_price']).then(df_product_data['current_price'])
    .otherwise(df_product_data['sold_price'])
    .alias('sold_price')
)
```

Comment: Generally polars is not a drop in replacement. Usage is slightly different. Could you provide a polars version of the code which does not work?

Comment: Polars is different. From what I can see in your code, you'll have to use **expressions**, like `df_product_data.with_columns([pl.when(...).then(...).otherwise(...), ...])`. But without a [mre] ...

Comment: You were misinformed if you thought polars was a dropin replacement for pandas. [See here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/migration/pandas/#key-syntax-differences)

Answer (score 1):

As for your polars example:

- `.with_column()` is now known as `.with_columns()`
- the use of `pl.date()` is misplaced

You need to turn `transaction_date` into a date which you can do with [`.str.to_date()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.to_date.html#polars.Expr.str.to_date)

```
.with_columns(pl.col('transaction_date').str.to_date())
```

`reorder_threshold` is a number of days, you can use [`pl.duration(days=)`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.duration.html#polars-duration) to turn this into a duration which you can substract with.

- you can use `pl.col('name')` instead of `df_product_name['name']`
- `.otherwise(None)` is the default - you can leave it out

```
data = {
    'transaction_date': ['2023-06-01', '2023-06-02', '2023-06-03'],
    'quantity_available': [0, 2, 1],
    'reorder_threshold': [5, 1, 3],
    'current_price': [10.0, 12.0, 8.0],
    'sold_price': [0, 15.0, 20.0],
}


product_sold_out_mask = (
    (pl.col('quantity_available') == 0)
    & (pl.col('reorder_threshold') >= 0)
)

(pl.DataFrame(data)
   .with_columns(pl.col('transaction_date').str.to_date())
   .with_columns(
       pl.when(product_sold_out_mask)
         .then(pl.col('transaction_date') - pl.duration(days = 'reorder_threshold'))
         .alias('sold_out_date')
   )
   .with_columns(
       pl.when(pl.col('sold_price') <= 0)
         .then(-999)
         .when(pl.col('sold_price') > 2.0 * pl.col('current_price'))
         .then(pl.col('current_price'))
         .otherwise(pl.col('sold_price'))
         .alias('sold_price')
   )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 6)
┌──────────────────┬────────────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────┬────────────┬───────────────┐
│ transaction_date ┆ quantity_available ┆ reorder_threshold ┆ current_price ┆ sold_price ┆ sold_out_date │
│ ---              ┆ ---                ┆ ---               ┆ ---           ┆ ---        ┆ ---           │
│ date             ┆ i64                ┆ i64               ┆ f64           ┆ f64        ┆ date          │
╞══════════════════╪════════════════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 2023-06-01       ┆ 0                  ┆ 5                 ┆ 10.0          ┆ -999.0     ┆ 2023-05-27    │
│ 2023-06-02       ┆ 2                  ┆ 1                 ┆ 12.0          ┆ 15.0       ┆ null          │
│ 2023-06-03       ┆ 1                  ┆ 3                 ┆ 8.0           ┆ 8.0        ┆ null          │
└──────────────────┴────────────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: One nitpick, I would make this sentence "you can use pl.col('name') instead of df_product_name['name']" stronger since in a `select`/`with_columns` context it is a *must* not just a *may*.

Comment: One additional question: Can we assign values to two columns simultaneously during execution? For instance, in the current example, we are assigning a value to the 'sold_out_date' column. Could we also assign 'sold' as 1 in the same execution?

Comment: @Rocky I think the simplest way is to repeat the condition e.g. `pl.when(product_sold_out_mask).then(1).alias('sold')`